# Limits for SOAP Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I'm creating a service in WS in Salesforce to receive thousands of calls per day. By Someone knows what is the limit of SOAP calls to my sales org Force can receive?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limits are based on edition & license count, the [online help](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm) has all the details.